# Stanford NLP - UnsupportedOperationException: Argument array lengths differ

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to follow the `How can I train my own NER model` tutorial from here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#b

When I run the test command to test the model performance:
`java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz -testFile jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv`

I get the following error:

```
Invoked on Thu May 10 15:40:41 IST 2018 with arguments: -loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz -testFile jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv
testFile=jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv
loadClassifier=ner-model.ser.gz
Loading classifier from ner-model.ser.gz ... done [0.2 sec].
Error on line 1: CHAPTER        O
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
Argument array lengths differ: [class edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TextAnnotation, class edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$AnswerAnnotation] vs. [CHAPTER, , O]
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel.initFromStrings(CoreLabel.java:263)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel.<init>(CoreLabel.java:150)
    ...
    ...
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1189)
   at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1133)
   at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1087)
   at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:3033)
```

I have used the provided training and test files. Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue was that the `jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv` file provided on Stanford site had an extra tab character. Once I removed that, it fixed the issue.