# Different precision/recall/f1 values when reproducing Stanford CoreNLP austen demo in CLI and Code

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to validate my Stanford CoreNLP based java code with the Jane Austen files from the [Stanford CRF FAQ](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html). I'm training as described in the FAQ in the CLI with the following command:

```sh
# Training with corenlp 3.9.2
java -cp stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop
# testing with corenlp 3.9.2
java -cp stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier \
    -loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz -testFile jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv
```

This gives me the following results:

```
CRFClassifier tagged 1999 words in 1 documents at 6227,41 words per second.
         Entity P   R   F1  TP  FP  FN
           PERS 0,8205  0,7273  0,7711  32  7   12
         Totals 0,8205  0,7273  0,7711  32  7   12
```

Now I have java code to train and test the model programmaticaly:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.SeqClassifierFlags;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.Triple;

public class train {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    
    System.out.println("Start NER training");
    
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(new File("data/eval/austen.prop")));
        SeqClassifierFlags flags = new SeqClassifierFlags(properties);
    CRFClassifier<CoreLabel> crf = new CRFClassifier<>(flags);
    
    crf.train();
    
    crf.serializeClassifier("data/eval/ner-model.ser.gz");
    Triple<Double,Double,Double> scores = crf.classifyAndWriteAnswers("data/eval/jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv", true);
    
    System.out.println("Scores:");
    System.out.format("    Precision:\t%.2f%%\n", scores.first);
    System.out.format("    Recall:\t%.2f%%\n", scores.second);
    System.out.format("    F1:\t\t%.2f%%\n", scores.third);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("End NER training done");

    }
}
```

This gives me different values for precision/recall/f1:

```
CRFClassifier tagged 1999 words in 1 documents at 12572,33 words per second.
         Entity P   R   F1  TP  FP  FN
           PERS 0,8250  0,7500  0,7857  33  7   11
         Totals 0,8250  0,7500  0,7857  33  7   11
Scores:
    Precision:  82,50%
    Recall: 75,00%
    F1:     78,57%
```

The testing, training and austen.prop files where taken unchanged from stanford. Only the testing file jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv was modified as described on dies [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270566/stanford-nlp-unsupportedoperationexception-argument-array-lengths-differ).

I read the [stanford sources](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/v3.9.2/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier.java) to see if i missed something, but my values kept unchanged.
What am I missing?

Thanks for help in advance.

**Update:** I did some further tests. It's definitively a training issue. The model trained with the cli has one mode false negative. I made a diff to see which entity is not detected:

```
371,372c371,372
< Miss  PERS    PERS
< Churchill PERS    PERS
---
> Miss  PERS    O
> Churchill PERS    O
```

It's 'Miss Churchill'.

**Update2:** Found it. It's the following line in edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier.java:

```java
crf.knownLCWords.setMaxSize(-1);
```

Unfortunately the field is not visible public. And the object returned by `crf.getKnownLCWords()` has no method `setMaxSize()`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you needed to alter the download.tsv file? I don't see extra tabs in it.

Comment: Thank you for our reply. I did: `curl -L -O https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/ner-example/jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv`. With this file I get the "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Argument array lengths differ" Exception. When I do a `:%s/\t\t/\t/g` in vi and run my test again it works. jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv has two tab chars.

Answer (score 0):

Some further reading of the CoreNLP sources lead to an solution. I casted the object returned by `crf.getKnownLCWords()` to a `MaxSizeConcurrentHashSet`. Now `setMaxSize()` is available and the Precision/Recall/F1 values are the same compared to the training with the CoreNLP CLI.

```java
CRFClassifier<CoreLabel> crf = new CRFClassifier<>(flags);
MaxSizeConcurrentHashSet<String> knownLCWords = (MaxSizeConcurrentHashSet<String>) crf.getKnownLCWords();
knownLCWords.setMaxSize(-1);
crf.train();
```